# RestKit object mapping of list within list

Tags: ios, restkit

the json api has a list of posts, and each post has a list of users that like this post.

post, user each has an entity in core data.

how RestKit do object mapping.

```
{
    posts:[
        {
            "postid":   1,
            "posttext":  "post1",
            "likeusers":[
                {
                    "uid":  1,
                    "username":  "user1"
                },
                {
                    "uid":  2,
                    "username":  "user2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "postid":   2,
            "posttext":  "post2",
            "likeusers":[
                {
                    "uid":  1,
                    "username":  "user1"
                },
                {
                    "uid":  2,
                    "username":  "user2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I read the book "RestKit for iOS" and then read the RestKit document, get too much information in a short time, and have no idea about this question. will make tries before ask question next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do the mapping:

```
// User mapping
RKEntityMapping *userMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"User"
                                                   inManagedObjectStore:yourManagedObjectStore];
userMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"userID"];
[userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                  @"uid": @"userID",
                                                  @"username": @"username",
                                                  }];

// Post mapping
RKEntityMapping *postMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Post"
                                                   inManagedObjectStore:yourManagedObjectStore];
postMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"postID"];
[postMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                  @"postid": @"postID",
                                                  @"posttext": @"postText",
                                                  }];

[postMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"likeusers"
                                                                            toKeyPath:@"likeUsers" withMapping:userMapping]];
```

Hope it helps.